# how to display data in a table column using fpdf

Tags: windows, fpdf

My piece of code is:

```
for ( $i=2060; $i< $FINAL; $i++ ) {
$pdf->Cell( 36, 12, ( '05/' .number_format( $dataRow[$i] ) ), 1, 0, 'C', $fill );
  }
```

expected pdf output as a column of cells using fpdf is:

```
05/2060
05/2061
05/2062
05/2063
05/2064
```

please guide me how to get the above desirable output.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 1 on the `ln` part instead of 0

```
 for ( $i=2060; $i< $FINAL; $i++ ) {
  $pdf->Cell( 36, 12, ( '05/' .number_format( $dataRow[$i] ) ), 1, 1, 'C', $fill );
 }
```

and make sure that $FINAL has a value and you can do '05/'.$i also, and $fill must be true or false

Comment: Thank you so much.